Dynamically adding classes to the elements in the root layout
The root layout (app/layout.tsx) is a server component, so the only way to dyncamically add classes to, say, body or main is to do it from a child client component.
According to this, this is one way:
useEffect(() => {        
  document.body.classList.add("font-light");
  document.body.classList.add("text-gray-700");
});

But I was wondering, is there a more Next.js-like or React-like way of doing this?

You can write the expression inline with the markup
<div className={`${someCondition === 'showFoo' ? 'foo-bar' : 'no-u'} some-static-class`}>


In apps/layout.tsx? But I can't use useState or any hook there because it's a server component.

add 'use client'; to the top of your component and now to can use, useState. But if you don't want to move the render then yeah old fashioned js way.
